# Python3 discord selfbot NameError: name 'tokens' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

When I run my file for my discord selfbot, it gives me the error NameError: name 'tokens' is not defined. I am quite new to programming and I don't know why. If you know how I can fix this, please let me know in a comment.

This is the part that is not working:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
def Selfbottokens():
    with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
        tokens = [token.strip("\n") for token in f.readlines()]
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    client.add_cog(client)
    loop.create_task(client.start(tokens[i], bot=False))
```

Comment: You can simplify your for loop as `for token in tokens`.

Comment: `tokens` is a local variable to the function. You can't access it outside of the function. Either `return` it from the function to the outer scope, or move your loop to be inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is not well indented

it should have been as follow:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
def Selfbottokens():
    with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
        tokens = [token.strip("\n") for token in f.readlines()]
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            client.add_cog(client)
            loop.create_task(client.start(tokens[i], bot=False))
```